# Best method to get constantly updated json data in laravel

Tags: php, json, ajax, laravel

I'm trying to implement the jquery component [jquery.mentionsInput](https://podio.github.io/jquery-mentions-input/) on my laravel app.

Essentially I'll be using this so my users can `@` mention other users in comment sections of a thread.

However, I want the callback to only fetch users who have posted in that thread, not all users on my site.

This jquery component fetches users one of two ways, the first is an existing array in JS: https://podio.github.io/jquery-mentions-input/assets/examples.js

The second is to fetch users from a json file like so: https://podio.github.io/jquery-mentions-input/assets/example2.js

So I'm guessing my best solution is to perhaps create a route in laravel that fetches the json data of all users for a particular post ID?

But I feel like this is perhaps not the best approach for this.

Suggestions?

Comment: Just instead of using `id` of a post, I would create a post `slug` and use that instead, also make sure to use `FormRequest` to authorize and validate the request

Answer (score 1):

Yes! you must create a separate route for each ajax operation. and send csrf in the header.

```
$.ajaxSetup({
    headers: {           
        'X-CSRF-TOKEN': csrfToken
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

1.You can use continuous ajax. But its cause extra bandwidth loss.

2.I suggest You to use [Laravel-echo with pusher](https://pusher-community.github.io/real-time-laravel/).

https://pusher-community.github.io/real-time-laravel/